# how to download to startup folder

Tags: powershell, compilation

I'm trying to compile:

```
(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("file", "$env:USERPROFILE\"Start Menu\Programs\Startup"")
```

But I get a **warning** to change "Start" from the "Start Menu" by `"Start-process"`. Something that makes no sense.

And for the same issue/line besisdes that warning I get an **error** saying `"Misssing ")" in method call"`. If I accept that suggest it gets :

```
(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("file", "$env:USERPROFILE\")Start Menu\Programs\Startup"")
```

Doing this I get the error `"Unexpected token 'Start' in expression or statement"`

What can I do to download a file to the startup folder using $env:USERPROFILE

Thanks

Comment: variables can expand without issues in a double-quoted string: `DownloadFile(...., "$env:USERPROFILE\Start Menu\Programs\Startup")` should work properly.

Comment: Also do note, that method overload is expecting a file name not a folder name: `DownloadFile (string address, string fileName);` you probably want to use `"$env:USERPROFILE\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Y.exe"`

Answer (score 3):

Your string quotes are interpreted as:

```
"$env:USERPROFILE\"Start Menu\Programs\Startup""
^ start           ^ end                       ^^ start end
```

Then the `Start Menu` part is outside the string and is confusing your IDE.

As per Santiago Squarzon's comments, it needs to be more like:

```
"$env:USERPROFILE\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\filename.ext"
```

Comment: It may be also worth advising OP to use a PS alternative like `Invoke-RestMethod -OutFile` and / or `Invoke-WebRequest`

Comment: @Santiago Squarzon how could Invoke-RestMethod -OutFile or Invoke-WebRequest be used here?

Comment: @sta0vr `Invoke-RestMethod https://url.to.my.exe -OutFile path/to/my.exe`